# Android: Download video one by one

Tags: android, video

I am using Download Manager in order to download video on Android devices. The thing is that I want to download multiple videos (one by one).

I research about it for a whole day but there are a few solutions about download single video.

Following, I found the same question here but there is no answer:
[How to Download 45 videos one by one non stop with Download Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349356/how-to-download-45-videos-one-by-one-non-stop-with-download-manager)

If you guys know how to do this, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: I use BroadcastReceiver to know whenever the download is completed. Then, I start the order, but I think it is not a good solution

Comment: Its one of doing things in a easier way. I don't seem to be there is any best way.

Comment: https://github.com/smanikandan14/ThinDownloadManager  check this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really want to say thank you for all of your comments. After a few more hours research, I think that using BroadcastReceiver to solve this problem should be the great solution. Following, I want to share the answer for someone who have the same problem as me.

I create a static function to handle download:

```
public static long downloadVideo(String myHTTPUrl, Context context) {
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(myHTTPUrl));
    request.setTitle("File download.");
    request.setDescription("File is being download...");

    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

    final String nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(myHTTPUrl, null,
            MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(myHTTPUrl));
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, nameOfFile);

    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    return manager.enqueue(request);
}
```

When I click on the button download, then it will run the following code:

```
long downloadReference = DownloadHandler.downloadVideo(videoUrls[0], v.getContext());
DownloadReceiver downloadReceiver = new DownloadReceiver(0, videoUrls, downloadReference);

//set filter to only when download is complete and register broadcast receiver
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, filter);
```

And here is the final step, the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class DownloadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private int videoIndex;
private String[] videoUrls;

private long downloadReference;

public DownloadReceiver(int videoIndex, String[] videoUrls, long downloadReference) {
    this.videoIndex = videoIndex;
    this.videoUrls = videoUrls;
    this.downloadReference = downloadReference;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
    if(downloadReference == referenceId){
        ++videoIndex;
        if (videoIndex < videoUrls.length) {
            downloadReference = DownloadHandler.downloadVideo(videoUrls[videoIndex], context);
            DownloadReceiver downloadReceiver = new DownloadReceiver(videoIndex, videoUrls, downloadReference);

            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
            context.registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, intentFilter);
            context.unregisterReceiver(this);
        }
    }
}
```

}